# geopandas dissolve overlapping polygons

Tags: dissolve, geopandas

Goal is to group polygon (1,2,4) and polygon (3) based on overlap. All polygons are part of the same shapefile layer.

[image]

In ArcMap I can simply do dissolve and uncheck Create multipart features.

[image]

However [dissolve](http://geopandas.org/aggregation_with_dissolve.html) in geopandas requires you to set an attribute to dissolve on. What would be the easiest alternative in geopandas?

Answer (score 15):

Using this example GeoSeries:

```
s = geopandas.GeoSeries([Polygon([(0, 0), (0, 2), (2, 2), (2, 0)]), Polygon([(0, 1), (0, 3), (2, 3), (2, 1)]),Polygon([(1, 0), (1, 2), (3, 2), (3, 0)]), Polygon([(4, 4), (4, 6), (6, 6), (6, 4)])])

s.plot(alpha=0.5, cmap='Set1')
```

[image]

We could create a matrix indicating which geometries are overlapping:

```
In [55]: overlap_matrix = s.apply(lambda x: s.overlaps(x)).values.astype(int)

In [56]: overlap_matrix
Out[56]: 
array([[0, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

And from that get the groups using scipy's connected components:

```
In [57]: from scipy.sparse.csgraph import connected_components

In [58]: connected_components(overlap_matrix)
Out[58]: (2, array([0, 0, 0, 1], dtype=int32))

In [59]: n, ids = connected_components(overlap_matrix)
```

And use `dissolve` based on those groups:

```
In [60]: df = geopandas.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': s, 'group': ids})

In [61]: res = df.dissolve(by='group')

In [62]: res
Out[62]: 
                                                geometry
group                                                   
0      POLYGON ((0 0, 0 1, 0 2, 0 3, 2 3, 2 2, 3 2, 3...
1                    POLYGON ((4 4, 4 6, 6 6, 6 4, 4 4))

In [63]: res.plot(cmap='Set1')
```

[image]

But note: I am certainly not sure if creating such a matrix is the most efficient way.
Further note, this would actually be a nice enhancement to geopandas to enable this somehow (or at least to have a good solution in the examples)

Comment: This outputs incorrect results if a starting polygon is entirely within another.

Comment: To redeem this, I suggest using [`intersects`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.intersects.html#geopandas.GeoSeries.intersects) instead of [`overlaps`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.overlaps.html).

Answer (score 10):

I found a workaround:

```
def explode(gdf):
    """    
    Will explode the geodataframe's muti-part geometries into single 
    geometries. Each row containing a multi-part geometry will be split into
    multiple rows with single geometries, thereby increasing the vertical size
    of the geodataframe. The index of the input geodataframe is no longer
    unique and is replaced with a multi-index. 

    The output geodataframe has an index based on two columns (multi-index) 
    i.e. 'level_0' (index of input geodataframe) and 'level_1' which is a new
    zero-based index for each single part geometry per multi-part geometry

    Args:
        gdf (gpd.GeoDataFrame) : input geodataframe with multi-geometries

    Returns:
        gdf (gpd.GeoDataFrame) : exploded geodataframe with each single 
                                 geometry as a separate entry in the 
                                 geodataframe. The GeoDataFrame has a multi-
                                 index set to columns level_0 and level_1

    """
    gs = gdf.explode()
    gdf2 = gs.reset_index().rename(columns={0: 'geometry'})
    gdf_out = gdf2.merge(gdf.drop('geometry', axis=1), left_on='level_0', right_index=True)
    gdf_out = gdf_out.set_index(['level_0', 'level_1']).set_geometry('geometry')
    gdf_out.crs = gdf.crs
    return gdf_out

df_all = df1.append(df2,ignore_index=True)
df_all["group"] = 1
dissolved = df_all.dissolve(by="group")
gdf_out = explode(dissolved)
gdf_out2 = gdf_out.reset_index()
```

[Notebook](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/rutgerhofste/6e7c6569616c2550568b9ce9cb4716a3) with the workaround (different polygons):

Comment: What is `df1` and `df2` here? As you mention you have a single shapefile with those polygons?

Comment: Ah, I understand what you are doing (apart from the append). This is indeed a nice solution, and if you just care about overlap, much simpler than mine!

Comment: You are right, for python testing I used http://geopandas.org/set_operations.html#the-different-overlay-operations instead of my shapefile. I used df1 and df2 from the docs and appended them to create something similar to the one-layer shapefile.

Comment: btw, I enjoy geopandas a lot, thank you for the hard work Joris

Answer (score 2):

I've tried to enhance @joris's answer

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon 
import geopandas as gpd 

s = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data=[1, 2, 3, 4], 
geometry=[Polygon([(0, 0), (0, 2), (2, 2), (2, 0)]),
          Polygon([(0, 1), (0, 3), (2, 3), (2, 1)]),
          Polygon([(1, 0), (1, 2), (3, 2), (3, 0)]), 
          Polygon([(4, 4), (4, 6), (6, 6), (6, 4)])], 
                     columns=['column'])

   column                                           geometry
0       1  POLYGON ((0.00000 0.00000, 0.00000 2.00000, 2....
1       2  POLYGON ((0.00000 1.00000, 0.00000 3.00000, 2....
2       3  POLYGON ((1.00000 0.00000, 1.00000 2.00000, 3....
3       4  POLYGON ((4.00000 4.00000, 4.00000 6.00000, 6....

s.plot(alpha=0.5, cmap='Set1')
```

[image]

```
s_ = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
  geometry=[s.unary_union]).explode(
  index_parts=False).reset_index(
  drop=True)

s_.plot(alpha=0.5, cmap='Set1')
```

[image]

If you need to work with data you can use `sjoin` and `dissolve` functions.

```
s_ = gpd.sjoin(s_, s, how='left').drop(columns=['index_right'])
s_.dissolve(s_.index, aggfunc='first')

geometry    column
0   POLYGON ((3.00000 0.00000, 2.00000 0.00000, 1....   1
1   POLYGON ((6.00000 6.00000, 6.00000 4.00000, 4....   4
```